# Store Gradle distribution in Azure devops artifacts?

Tags: gradle, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

The distribution url in my gradle-wrapper.properties is pointing at
https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip
That is, its pointing towards the internet. Is it possible to use the Azure devops artifacts url instead, and let it cache gradle distributions for future proofing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We (Azure Artifacts) don't have anything that would handle that directly. You might be able to script something up to store the files using [Universal Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops), but  you'd have to handle all the details yourself.